# Selenium + Python: how can we close all opened tabs except the first tab/main tab?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python, browser-automation, performance-testing

This is my code,

```
   '''
import time
 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
num = str(datetime.datetime.now())
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("https://my.eventbuizz.com/_super/analytics_requests")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("text")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("text")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='login']").click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Google Analytics')]").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Analytics Requests')]").click()
ActionChains = ActionChains(driver)
time.sleep(2)
 
lists = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class= 'gradeA']/td[1]")
for list_item in lists:
    print(len(lists))
    print(type(lists))
    print(list_item.text)
    output = list_item.text
 
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.get("https://my.eventbuizz.com/_super/organizerEvent/organizerEventList")
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='event_name']").send_keys(output)
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Search']").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[normalize-space()='Auto Login']").click()
    time.sleep(5)
 
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='searchText']").send_keys(output)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='btn_sbt']").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='img-center']//a").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    event_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='event_name']").get_attribute('value')
    print("Event Name = " + event_name)
    time.sleep(5)
    a = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body[1]/section[1]/section[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/em[1]").text
    ab = a[8:]
    print("Event URl = " + ab)
 
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[3])
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.get("https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/a213435779w295029133p256179771/admin")
    time.sleep(4)
    email_phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']")
    time.sleep(2)
    email_phone.send_keys("eb.march.eventbuizz2021@gmail.com")
    driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()
    password = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']")))
    password.send_keys("text")
    driver.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click()
    time.sleep(20)
    # driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='ga-dialog-title-close']").click()
    # time.sleep(6)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Create Property')]").click()
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='name']").click()
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='name']").send_keys(event_name)
    time.sleep(4)
 
    countries = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class='menu-open-button-label-text']")
    for country in countries:
        if country.text == "United Kingdom":
            country.click()
            break
    time.sleep(2)
    country_name = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class='option-container ng-star-inserted']")
    for count in country_name:
        if count.text == "Denmark":
            count.click()
            break
 
    time.sleep(2)
    amount_code = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='option-item-wrapper ng-star-inserted']")
    for code in amount_code:
        if code.text == "Danish Krone (DKK DKK)":
            code.click()
            break
 
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Show advanced options')]").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='mat-slide-toggle-thumb']").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    end = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Website URL')]")
    driver.execute_script("document.body.scrollIntoView();", end)
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='url']").send_keys(ab)
 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='mat-radio-8-input']//span[@class='mat-radio-label-content']").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Next')]").click()
    time.sleep(2)
 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='mat-radio-2-input']//span[@class='mat-radio-label-content']").click()
 
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='mat-checkbox-2-input']//span[@class='mat-checkbox-inner-container']").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space()='Create']").click()
    time.sleep(20)
    driver.switch_to.frame("galaxyIframe")
    time.sleep(5)
    track = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='_GACjb']").text
    print(print("Tracking ID = " + track))
 
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//mat-icon[contains(text(),'arrow_back')]").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'View Access Management')]").click()
    time.sleep(8)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Add access to new users']//span[@class='mat-button-wrapper']").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[normalize-space()='Add users']").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_id("mat-chip-list-input-0").send_keys(
        "analytics47@api-project-770804776074.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[normalize-space()='Add']").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//mat-icon[normalize-space()='close']").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'View Settings')]").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    view_id = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='content view-id']").text
    print("View ID =" + view_id)
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[4])
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.get("https://my.eventbuizz.com/_admin/add_google_analytics")
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Google analytics email']").clear()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Google analytics email']").send_keys(
        " analytics47@api-project-770804776074.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Google Analytics Code']").clear()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Google Analytics Code']").send_keys(track)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Google profile ID']").clear()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Google profile ID']").send_keys(view_id)
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='save-event']").click()
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-sm log-out text-right']").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[5])
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[normalize-space()='Statistics']").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[normalize-space()='Accept all cookies']").click()
 
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[3])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//md-icon[@md-font-icon='realtime-icon']").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='ga-nav-link-label ga-nav-link-no-icon']").click()
    time.sleep(3)
    print("************************ Google analytics added successfully **************************** ")
 
    with open('Text.txt', mode='w') as f:
        f.write("Event_name" + "          " + "Event_Tracking_ID" + "\n")
        for post in event_name:
            f.write(post)
        f.write("          ")
        for post1 in track:
            f.write(post1)
        f.write("\n")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    '''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[5]).close()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[4]).close()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[3]).close()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2]).close()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]).close()
```

Basically, switch to the particular window that you want to close and then call `driver.close()` method on it.

You can put the above in a loop. It would look something like:

```
for x in range(1, 6):
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[x]).close()
```

Comment: Is it is possible to handle it with a loop .?

Comment: Yes. Put the statement inside a for loop and replace the handle id with the loop counter.

Comment: can you write a code please @IAmMilinPatel

Comment: I've added a sample code with For loop in the answer. That should work. If it does, you can mark the answer as accepted.